# How to configure JAVA HOME with OpenJDK?

Tags: java, ubuntu

I installed the SERPOSCOPE program on my Ubuntu 18.04 server. It needs Java to work, so I installed OpenJDK :

```
$ sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
$ java -version

openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.04.1-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

Here are the installation instructions. There is a comment about the Java folder but I did not understand what I had to do :

https://github.com/serphacker/serposcope

https://serposcope.serphacker.com/en/doc/install.html

The problem and there is a problem with Java and SERPOSCOPE refuses to start :

```
ubuntu@serp-example-com:~$ sudo systemctl status serposcope
● serposcope.service - LSB: serposcope rank checker
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/serposcope; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-05-12 16:06:15 CEST; 7s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 9785 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/serposcope start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 12 16:06:15 serp-example-com systemd[1]: Starting LSB: serposcope rank checker...
May 12 16:06:15 serp-example-com serposcope[9785]: Can't find JAVA_HOME, java seems not installed on this OS
May 12 16:06:15 serp-example-com systemd[1]: serposcope.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 12 16:06:15 serp-example-com systemd[1]: serposcope.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 12 16:06:15 serp-example-com systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: serposcope rank checker.


ubuntu@serp-example-com:~$ journalctl -xe
May 12 16:06:02 serp-example-com groupadd[9636]: group added to /etc/gshadow: name=serposcope
May 12 16:06:02 serp-example-com groupadd[9636]: new group: name=serposcope, GID=1001
May 12 16:06:02 serp-example-com useradd[9641]: new user: name=serposcope, UID=111, GID=65534, home=/var/lib/serposcope, shell=/usr/sbin/
May 12 16:06:02 serp-example-com usermod[9647]: change user 'serposcope' password
May 12 16:06:02 serp-example-com chage[9652]: changed password expiry for serposcope
May 12 16:06:03 serp-example-com systemd[1]: Reloading.
May 12 16:06:03 serp-example-com systemd[1]: Reloading.
May 12 16:06:03 serp-example-com sudo[9593]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 12 16:06:07 serp-example-com sudo[9749]:   ubuntu : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ubuntu ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/ufw allow 7134
May 12 16:06:07 serp-example-com sudo[9749]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ubuntu(uid=0)
May 12 16:06:08 serp-example-com sudo[9749]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 12 16:06:15 serp-example-com sudo[9782]:   ubuntu : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ubuntu ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start serposcop
May 12 16:06:15 serp-example-com sudo[9782]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ubuntu(uid=0)
May 12 16:06:15 serp-example-com systemd[1]: Starting LSB: serposcope rank checker...
-- Subject: Unit serposcope.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit serposcope.service has begun starting up.
May 12 16:06:15 serp-example-com serposcope[9785]: Can't find JAVA_HOME, java seems not installed on this OS
May 12 16:06:15 serp-example-com systemd[1]: serposcope.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 12 16:06:15 serp-example-com sudo[9782]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 12 16:06:15 serp-example-com systemd[1]: serposcope.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 12 16:06:15 serp-example-com systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: serposcope rank checker.
-- Subject: Unit serposcope.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit serposcope.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
May 12 16:06:18 serp-example-com kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens3 OUT= MAC=fa:16:3a:c8:b3:fc:0a:c5:39:6b:41:e2:08:00 SRC=185.10.68.55 DST=51.8
May 12 16:06:23 serp-example-com sudo[9813]:   ubuntu : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ubuntu ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl status serposco
May 12 16:06:23 serp-example-com sudo[9813]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ubuntu(uid=0)
May 12 16:06:23 serp-example-com sudo[9813]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

ubuntu@serp-example-com:~$ sudo JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 systemctl status serposcope

```
● serposcope.service - LSB: serposcope rank checker
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/serposcope; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-05-12 17:43:02 CEST; 9min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 10202 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/serposcope start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 12 17:43:02 serp-example-com systemd[1]: Starting LSB: serposcope rank checker...
May 12 17:43:02 serp-example-com serposcope[10202]: Can't find JAVA_HOME, java seems not installed on this OS
May 12 17:43:02 serp-example-com systemd[1]: serposcope.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 12 17:43:02 serp-example-com systemd[1]: serposcope.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 12 17:43:02 serp-example-com systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: serposcope rank checker.
```

Comment: What does `echo $JAVA_HOME` show?

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp It shows nothing

Comment: Try setting the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable using `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk` maybe the path is a bit different on your device. Check the path before.

Comment: This is not a programming question. It's a server/configuration question. It may belong in SuperUser or AskUbuntu or even ServerFault - make sure you check their "on topic" pages.

Comment: To see the exact value to set for JAVA_HOME run 'update-java-alternatives -l'

Comment: From the second link `So if you did install Java to /opt/java/1.8 then ... JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/1.8`  So you should set JAVA_HOME to whatever path you installed Java to.

Comment: @Mihai Here is the result of the command `java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64`

Comment: Then use `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64` to set the environment variable. After that try running serposcope again.

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp I executed your command but it refuses to start

Comment: @tropcool Of course it doesn't because you set the variable in your context and then run the service as sudo. Can you try and run: sudo JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 systemctl status serposcope

Comment: @Mihai It does not work, I added the result at the end of my question

Comment: @tropcool I managed to get an Ubuntu environment and test. Run 'systemctl edit serposcope'. This should open an editor. Edit the file (/etc/systemd/system/serposcope.service.d/override.conf): Under group [Service] (create if doesn't exist) add: Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"

Comment: @tropcool If it is difficult to read this I will write it as solution so it is better formatted

Comment: @Mihai Can you answer? The file is empty `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/serposcope.service.d/override.conf`

Comment: @tropcool Perfect so add 2 lines: one with [Service] and the second one with Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"  Then save it and try to start the service

Comment: @Mihai Can you give an answer because there is too much comment ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First find out the location of Java home with `update-java-alternatives -l` (the last part is the path to remember).

Then run `systemctl edit serposcope` and this should open an editor. Add the following lines:

```
[Service]
Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"
```

Where the value from JAVA_HOME is the one from the first point.

Try to start your service with `sudo systemctl status serposcope`

Comment: Thank you, it works. Why is not this already done with the installation of OpenJDK ?

Comment: At the moment I don't know but I'll check if I find something.

Comment: Is the problem coming from a bug in SERPOSCOPE

Comment: From what I see in the section "Ubuntu & Debian install instructions" (https://serposcope.serphacker.com/en/doc/install.html) it is more a user error ;) There is clearly specifies to setup JAVA_HOME before starting the installation. Probably if that is done then the installer would also correctly setup the service. The same page also mentions you can set JAVA_HOME in /etc/default/serposcope. In my opinion it is pretty well documented. I don't know if they could've automated it even more...

Comment: So the best will be to do `$ sudo nano /etc/default/serposcope
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64` before starting SERPOSCOPE ?

Comment: don't know if the best but surely the easier way.

Answer (score 0):

I got my work following this

```
[Unit]
Description= Application
After=syslog.target

[Service]
Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk"
ExecStart= java -jar /app-path/target/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
ExecStop= /bin/kill -15 $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```